# Wordpress - Custom theme - Template Name not showing Template in Page Attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a custom theme in Wordpress from scratch.

I want to create different templates for different pages. I have create a file named *page-contactus.php* in my theme folder where there is this code:
[image]

But if I want to associate this template into one of the pages, I can not see the Template dropdown in Page Attributes in my dashboard.

[image]

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use):

> Important! Do not use page- as a prefix, as WordPress will interpret the file as a specialized template, meant to apply to only one page on your site.

So just change the file name. We prefix all of our templates with 'tpl' but anything else should work, too.

Comment: Hi Chris.
Thanks for your reply. I have already changed by _tpl-contactus.php_ and still not working... any other idea?